# How to replace an image in TSpeedButton with another image in an ImageList?

Tags: delphi, timagelist

In my program, the image of SpeenButton set by imagelist. I need the image change with another image in the imagelist, when I click the speedbutton. How can I do that?

Comment: VCL or FMX? They both have a `TSpeedButton` which are very different from each other. VCL's has a single `Glyph` property, FMX's has `Images` and `ImageIndex` properties

Comment: If VCL, something like `MyImageList.GetBitmap(..., MySpeedButton.Glyph)` IIRC.

Comment: I usually advice people not to use speed buttons at all, because they are not windowed controls. Hence they cannot receive keyboard focus. Consequently, they become more difficult to use for keyboard-first users like me: I cannot tab me to them and activate them with Enter or Space. Also, I think they have no `Default` or `Cancel` properties. However, you _can_ give them accelerators (like `'&New hippogriff'`), so I do advice you to do so if applicable. Otherwise, make sure your GUI is conveniently usable with only the keyboard in other ways.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are talking about VCL `TSpeedbutton`, you can place a `TActionList` on your form and connect it to your `TImagelist`. Then create an action in the actionlist, set its `ImageIndex` to the desired image. Now connect the `TSpeedbutton` to that action. In the `OnExecute` event of the action change the actions `ImageIndex` property to the new value. The speedbutton now shows the new image.